# Javascript how to use portfinder

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I just started learning Javascript and I was wondering how can I use the portfinder.getPort() function in one of my functions to get a random port every time. This is my code right now:

```
var portfinder = require('portfinder')

  portfinder.getPort(function (err, port) {
      var p = port;
  });

function toAddress (name) {
 return name + p;
}
```

I know this is wrong but how can I use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you already have a random free port in your declared variable p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the usage example on the project's [Github](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder) page:

There is also examples on the [NPM Page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portfinder)

From the docs:

```
var portfinder = require('portfinder');

  portfinder.getPort(function (err, port) {
    //
    // `port` is guaranteed to be a free port
    // in this scope.
    //
  });
```

In your code the problem seems to be the way your accessing `p` is not correct, because it's in a closure and not available outside of the scope of that function.

If you move the declaration of `p` outside the closure you can then access it from the other function but a better way would be to pass it to `toAddress`.

Comment: Thank. I have looked into that linked and I will change my code now.